# OAuth2 Spring security with Google login doesn't work

Tags: spring, spring-boot, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, spring-oauth2

I found a really good tutorial on third-party login with Spring security in the link below,
It contains both front-end and back-end code.

https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-security-oauth2-social-login-part-1/

Github : https://github.com/callicoder/spring-boot-react-oauth2-social-login-demo

Everything works perfectly locally as well as in a cloud server in a normal docker container.
But if I put this code behind a reverse proxy preferably Nginx (using docker swarm) there seems to be some issue in the redirection. In my console, I'll get the authorization_request_not_found error. I have basically googled and tried everything but for some reason, it's not working. I am definitely missing something. So any help is much appreciated. The required code snippets are down below.

For example, if our domain is test.oauth.com

i) Nginx proxy's default.conf

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name test.oauth.com;
        ssl_certificate /home/bundle_chained.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /home/private.key;
        
        proxy_set_header     X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header     X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header     X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
        proxy_set_header     Host                $http_host;
        proxy_set_header     X-Forwarded-Host    $server_name;
        proxy_set_header     X-Forwarded-Server  $host;
        proxy_set_header     X-Forwarded-Port    $server_port;
        proxy_set_header     Cookie              $http_cookie;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-error.log;

       location /login {
                    rewrite ^/login(.*)$ $1 break;
                    proxy_pass http://test-login-server:8080/;
                    proxy_redirect off;
        }

        location / {
                rewrite ^/(.*)$ /$1 break;
                proxy_pass http://test-react-server/;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection ‘upgrade’;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name test.oauth.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

ii) Nginx react server's default.conf

```
server {
        listen 80;
        
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name test.oauth.com;

        location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

        proxy_cache cache_zone;
        proxy_cache_background_update on;
        proxy_cache_lock on;
        proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout http_500;
        proxy_cache_valid 200 10m;
        add_header X-Cached $upstream_cache_status;

        }


        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }
}
```

I am using another Nginx server (test-react-server) to serve the front-end build.

iii) Application.yml of Spring

```
server:
  forward-headers-strategy: NATIVE

spring:
    datasource:
        url: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/spring_social?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
        username: <username>
        password: <password>


    jpa:
        show-sql: true
        hibernate:
            ddl-auto: update
            naming-strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
        properties:
            hibernate:
                dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    security:
      oauth2:
        client:
          registration:
            google:
              clientId: <google-client-id>
              clientSecret: <google-client-secret>
              redirectUri: "{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/callback/{registrationId}"
              scope:
                - email
                - profile
            facebook:
              clientId: <facebook-client-id>
              clientSecret: <facebook-client-secret>
              redirectUri: "{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/callback/{registrationId}"
              scope:
                - email
                - public_profile
            github:
              clientId: <github-client-id>
              clientSecret: <github-client-secret>
              redirectUri: "{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/callback/{registrationId}"
              scope:
                - user:email
                - read:user
          provider:
            facebook:
              authorizationUri: https://www.facebook.com/v3.0/dialog/oauth
              tokenUri: https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/oauth/access_token
              userInfoUri: https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/me?fields=id,first_name,middle_name,last_name,name,email,verified,is_verified,picture.width(250).height(250)
app:
  auth:
    tokenSecret: 04ca023b39512e46d0c2cf4b48d5aac61d34302994c87ed4eff225dcf3b0a218739f3897051a057f9b846a69ea2927a587044164b7bae5e1306219d50b588cb1
    tokenExpirationMsec: 864000000

  cors:
    #allowedOrigins: http://localhost:3000
    allowedOrigins: https://test.oauth.com,https://test.oauth.com/login
  oauth2:
    authorizedRedirectUris:
      #- http://localhost:3000/oauth2/redirect
      - https://test.oauth.com/oauth2/redirect
```

iv) Front-end's package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-social",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "http://test-react-server",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-s-alert": "^1.4.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

v) Front-end's index.js

```
export const API_BASE_URL = 'https://test.oauth.com/login';

export const ACCESS_TOKEN = 'accessToken';

export const OAUTH2_REDIRECT_URI = 'https://test.oauth.com/oauth2/redirect'


export const GOOGLE_AUTH_URL = API_BASE_URL + '/oauth2/authorize/google?redirect_uri=' + OAUTH2_REDIRECT_URI;
export const FACEBOOK_AUTH_URL = API_BASE_URL + '/oauth2/authorize/facebook?redirect_uri=' + OAUTH2_REDIRECT_URI;
export const GITHUB_AUTH_URL = API_BASE_URL + '/oauth2/authorize/github?redirect_uri=' + OAUTH2_REDIRECT_URI;
```

[image: Screenshot of error-1]

[image: Screenshot of error-2]

vi) Stack trace of error

```
org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException: [authorization_request_not_found] 
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:222)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:769)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1726)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

I dumped the stack trace in OAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler class.

Update:

For anyone stumbling upon the same issue. I was not able to solve this issue using the above cookie-based configuration. However, I understood why it was not working.

i) User clicks on the sign-in with google. At this time the OAuth2 state will be saved in the cookie.

ii) User will be redirected to the google login page with the appropriate client id and client secret in the URL which the backend will construct

iii) After the user enters the credentials and the sign-in is successful, google will redirect the browser to the redirect-URI provided by the backend in step 1.

iv) Now spring will match the initial OAuth2 request with the data sent by google.

In our case, it tries to get from the cookie. But for some reason, it won't get the cookie that it stored initially which will result in an [authorization_request_not_found] error.

Also if the client explicitly disables cookies in the browser then the above implementation wont work.

So I changed the above configuration from cookie-based implementation to DB-based implementation. This way I can have any amount of backend servers running behind the proxy since the DB will be shared between all the servers.

- WebSecurityConfig.java

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


   // other config


   @Bean
   public DBOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository dbAuthorizationRequestRepository() {
       return new DBOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository();
   }


   // other config


   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       
       // other config


       http.authorizationRequestRepository(dbAuthorizationRequestRepository())


       // other cofig
   }


}
```

- DBOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository.java

```
public class DBOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository implements 
    AuthorizationRequestRepository<OAuth2AuthorizationRequest> {

    @Autowired
    public OauthStateRepository oauthStateRepository;


    @Override
    public OAuth2AuthorizationRequest loadAuthorizationRequest(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        String state = httpServletRequest.getParameter("state");
        OauthState oauthState = oauthStateRepository.findOauthStateByState(state);
        return deserialize(oauthState.getSerializedValue(), OAuth2AuthorizationRequest.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void saveAuthorizationRequest(OAuth2AuthorizationRequest oAuth2AuthorizationRequest, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {
        String id = Generators.timeBasedGenerator().generate().toString();
        BigInteger timeStamp = BigInteger.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
        oauthStateRepository.saveState(id, httpServletRequest.getSession().getId(), serialize(oAuth2AuthorizationRequest), httpServletRequest.getParameter("redirect_uri"), oAuth2AuthorizationRequest.getState() ,timeStamp);
    }

    @Override
    public OAuth2AuthorizationRequest removeAuthorizationRequest(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        return this.loadAuthorizationRequest(httpServletRequest);
    }


    public static String serialize(Object object) {
        return Base64.getUrlEncoder()
                .encodeToString(SerializationUtils.serialize(object));
    }

    public static <T> T deserialize(String value, Class<T> cls) {
        return cls.cast(SerializationUtils.deserialize(
                Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(value)));
    }


}
```

- OauthState.java

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class OauthState {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String sessionId;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String serializedValue;

    private String redirectUri;

    private String state;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "bigint default 0")
    private BigInteger timestamp;
}
```

- OauthStateRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface OauthStateRepository extends JpaRepository<OauthState, Integer> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT id, redirect_uri, serialized_value , session_id , state, timestamp FROM oauth_state WHERE state = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    OauthState findOauthStateByState(String state);

    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query(value = "INSERT INTO oauth_state (id, redirect_uri, serialized_value, session_id, state, timestamp) VALUES  (?1,?2,?3,?4,?5,?6)", nativeQuery = true)
    void saveState(String id, String redirect_uri, String serialized_value, String session_id, String state ,BigInteger timestamp);

    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query(value = "DELETE FROM oauth_state WHERE state = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    void deleteOauthStateByState(String id);

    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query(value = "DELETE FROM oauth_state WHERE timestamp between 0 and ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    void deleteOauthStateByTimeStamp(BigInteger timeStamp);
}
```

Using the above configuration Spring will be able to successfully store and retrieve the OAuth2 state data whenever it's required. You have to make sure that Invalid state data won't be stored in the table. For that, you can use the scheduler to clean up invalid data from the OAuth2 state table every day or so.

Comment: Looks like this could be your issue
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59905769/spring-security-oauth2-authorization-request-not-found

Comment: @KshitijJoshi , Yes I have gone through that article before posting my question. But I have tried everything in the Answers section of that post. Also, server.forward.headers are deprecated in spring the new property is server.forward-headers-strategy which I am using in my application.yml.