# Azure AD redirected to /login?error when pressing back button after successful login

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, azure-active-directory

Project is running on using Spring boot with Vue.js as the front end.

Following are the versions used in pom

`azure-spring-boot-starter-active-directory : 3.9.0`

`java : 17`

`spring.boot.version : 2.7.0`

The application was build by following this sample project [ms-identity-java-spring-tutorial](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-spring-tutorial/tree/main/1-Authentication/sign-in) found  [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/ms-identity-msal-java-samples/ms-identity-java-spring-tutorial/?source=recommendations).

I was successfully able to login to the project, but when I press the back button, I get this page:

[image]

When I press back again, it's followed by this page:

[image]

If I press back again, it goes to here:

[image]

We have not configured any error page either on front end or backend. We even tried make a custom page and also tried with an api endpoint with this URL and still it's redirecting to this same page, which I believe is from Azure.

Also the browser redirects to this same page when there are multiple users logged in at the same time on the same browser.

This is the SecurityConfig Class. I have not created any extra layer of securiry classes since all the requests seems to be working properly with a JSESSIONID which was passed on from Azure to the frontend after login. I am not that expert in Spring Security and don't know if I am missing out on some required validations anywhere.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class AADSecurityConfig extends AADWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").authenticated();

        http.csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

[image]

Is there any way to bypass this page and redirect to the home page if the user is logged in?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact that you are receiving both the "authorization request not found" error and the AADSTS900561 error, it sounds like you might have the wrong domain configured on the app service.

Troubleshooting steps to try:

1. Make sure that the redirect URL set in the app registration matches exactly what you have configured in the app itself.
2. Set server.use-forward-headers=true
3. Confirm that the Logout URL is set correctly.

See related issue: [Spring security authorization request not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59905769/spring-security-oauth2-authorization-request-not-found)

Otherwise the AADSTS900561 error is normally caused by browser extensions blocking third party cookies. I've documented a solution for that issue [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/94885/aadsts900561-the-endpoint-only-accepts-post-reques.html).