# OAuth2 spring security with google callback not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

i have developed the micro service application, in that application there is a service call user service which is running on port `8281`. This service handle the authentications. when i test the service in local environment this is worked fine. But if i call this service using zuul api gateway this is not working. following property in the `application.yml` file is use to get the redirect url in the local environment. This is worked fine.

```
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          google:
            redirectUri: "http://localhost:8281/oauth2/callback/google"
```

But if i change this property as follow for connect with zuul api gateway.

```
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          google:
            redirectUri: "http://localhost:8080/api/user/oauth2/callback/google"
```

This is not working and is throw this error message `[authorization_request_not_found]`. localhost:8080 is the zuul api gateway. zuul has configure to forward request to user service like this.

```
zuul:
  prefix: /api
  routes:
    auth-service:
      path: /user/**
      serviceId: USER-SERVICE
      stripPrefix: true
      sensitiveHeaders: Cookie,Set-Cookie
```

so why this error is thrown ?

Comment: Well, with this config the redirect path will be /user/bla, so it starts with /user. Is that correct?

Comment: yes this is correct.` /user` for the user service. then call back endpoint is `oauth2/callback/google`

Comment: So how does this end up on your user service running on port 8281? Do you have a zuul filter which changes the host?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Spring security oauth, using a custom OAuth provider, I get \[authorization\_request\_not\_found\], should I handle the callback method myself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50908023/using-spring-security-oauth-using-a-custom-oauth-provider-i-get-authorization)